# Can a schedule be executed from future method?

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, future

One cannot execute a batch from a future annotated method. It is also impossible to have a trigger reacting to changes in future calling a batch.

I cannot find if it is possible to execute a schedule from a future method (or a `System.scheduleBatch`) which will then in turn execute a batch, similar to a older trick of calling a schedule from a batch finish to link batches.

Comment: Very interesting. What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we do that.  Dan Appleman did a dreamforce session about exactly that.  See [here for more](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24446/how-to-deploy-apex-classes-that-are-scheduled)

We chain batch, which schedules a job to restart that batch.  It runs round the clock, and is one of my favorite things I've ever built.