# Scheduled batch job from InstallHandler and further upgrades of managed package

Tags: managed-package, scheduled-apex

As I understand the further upgrade can fail if we try to update the class which already has scheduled job in the managed package, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, That is right. You can avoid it by writing your logic on other classes and just call it from the scheduler class.

[How to deploy apex classes that are scheduled](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24446/how-to-deploy-apex-classes-that-are-scheduled)

In older version scheduled classes and all other classes which are refereed in scheduled class were used to be lock. With new version now only scheduled classes are locked. So if you move your logic in other classes it should fix your problem.

Comment: @Natallia were you able to confirm this?

Comment: well, I can't reproduce that. Maybe if any issue existed for 1GP, it was fixed for 2GP