# How to manage the governor limit : Maximum number of Apex classes scheduled concurrently : 100

Tags: apex, governorlimits, job, scheduled-job

I launch a batch which call a lot of scheduled job. But I reach the governor limit :

> Maximum number of Apex classes scheduled concurrently : 100

I'm wondering what happens when this limit is reached. The next scheduled jobs are waiting the number of scheduled jobs is lower than 100 for being executed or are they all cancelled ?

And is there to way to manage the number of scheduled jobs to avoir reaching this limit ? For example wait before schedule a new job if we are near the limit.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need so many scheduled jobs?

Comment: I have to update several millions of objects. To do this I need to call an external URL to retreive datas in asynchronous way. I call this URL for each pack of 2000 records. That's why I schedule a lot of jobs.

Comment: Have you considered using Batch Apex and 'daisy chaining' them together? I think that would be more appropriate than scheduling lots of jobs

Comment: How can I do that ? Because the batch take the several millions objects in entry and then process them 2000 by 2000. How the next batch will know which objects are already processed and which not ?

Comment: I think you can update 10,000 at a time (i.e. maximum number of records affected by DML statements). Do you update the record to say that it is updated? If so, you can exclude those records from you Query in the batch `start` method (i.e. so it doesn't select them for reprocessing).

Comment: Yes the records are updated, but in asynchronous way so I'm afraid of if I have 5 batches running in the same time, some of them take the same records in entry.

Comment: if you used the Dan Appleman async pattern, you would only need one scheduled job but would have unlimited headroom - see: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24448/2602

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get over 100 scheduled jobs limit, the next schedules are being canceled that's why they invented FlexQueue. The way to manage more than 100 jobs scheduled is to use mentioned feature called FlexQueue. It gives you additional 100 jobs to be kept in a queue waiting for execution. Currently this feature is in pilot but it will be released soon (probably Spring'15). For details please check the [manual](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_apex_flex_queue.htm&language=en_US) and more generic description about the FQ on [Kaplan's blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/05/flex-batch-apex-muscles-flexqueue.html).

Comment: this makes sense for the OP's scenario of a batch job launching other jobs, but in cases where you want a job to run on a predefined schedule the flex queue isn't what you want