# How to limit the asynchronous job running in salesforce

Tags: asynchronous

I am using Queueuable Interface in trigger like this,

```
System.enqueueJob(new testobjectmethod(trigger.new,trigger.oldMap))
```

My Queueuable class:

```
public class testobjectmethod implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts {
       test__c[] newList;
       Map<id,test__c> oldMap;
public testobjectmethod(test__c[] newRecords,Map<id,test__c> oldRecords){
       newList = newRecords;
       oldMap  = oldRecords;
}
public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        Handlerclass.test(newList,oldMap);
    }

}
```

**Daily in 24 hours period , it is running more times, whenever the record operation performes asynchronously.while scheduling new job interface, i am facing the error - we ran into an error “You have exceeded the maximum number (100) of Apex  scheduled jobs”**

How to overcome this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manage the governor limit : Maximum number of Apex classes scheduled concurrently : 100](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53433/how-to-manage-the-governor-limit-maximum-number-of-apex-classes-scheduled-conc)

Comment: what i need to change in my code for using apex flex queue?

Answer (score 2):

This error cannot be caused by queueable classes, as they are not subject to a 100 limit. Somewhere in your code you have either System.schedule or System.scheduleBatch that is causing this error; you'll need to address this issue in that code. Note that Batches should generally not be called from a trigger for this reason.

Comment: while removing this queuable from the code, it is working, i am not facing any error

Comment: This queuable is daily running with so many times like this batches processed 0 and batches failed 0 in apex jobs

Comment: @VinothBalasubramaniyan That's only because you have a trigger that's loading too many Schedulable or scheduleBatch calls. You will need to address the problem at its source.

Comment: ok thank you, if we change it you future method is it work?

Comment: @VinothBalasubramaniyan Maybe. You're limited to one asynchronous call while using Queueable, so some restructuring may be necessary.

Comment: ok thank you that works, but i am performing record operation multiple times, trigger is calling multiple times. if i limit the asynchronous call , it wont affect the method execution right?

Comment: if i limit the one asynchronous call, it wont affect method execution right?