# Any work around to run 100+ jobs run or way

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

While saving 100+ jobs at a specified time i am getting error **"You have exceeded the maximum number (100) of Apex scheduled jobs"**

If i want to use one scheduler to run all , we gonna have two issues.

1 . Lets take administrator, they can able to see all the records . 
2.  which are non administators,they can able to see some records which are accessible by them only we are supposed to send.

i am wondering how can we give running as user to some other user as it is taking logged in user.
(not possible to update running as user)

Any work around to update the running as user else how can we pass running as user to schedule.

Comment: Do you really need 100+ separate jobs schedules for 6PM daily? Couldn't you have one job that starts a batch (or a small number of batches).

Comment: Actually there are 1000+ users ,they can schedule any no of jobs seperately. individual logins

Comment: Why do they users need to schedule jobs individually? You might need to create some form of queuing mechanism. There was a great talk on a message queuing architecture at Dreamforce. The video isn't up yet, but [I snapped a few shots of the slides](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/10/dreamforce-2014-round-up-summary.html#queue).

Comment: Lets take user1 is administrator, he can able to see all the data but not user1(not administrator) as he got no accessability to see data. if i schedule the job from user1 all data which is accesable by user1 going to all users

Comment: Maybe see if you can expand out your scenario in the question a bit. What are these scheduled jobs doing where the initiating users permissions need to be enforced?

Comment: Hi @DanielBallinger , i just edited the question. can you please check once

Comment: In addition to @Daniel Ballinger's comment - look at Dan Appleman's Async Pattern -- it will allow you to have only one scheduled job with an unlimited number of async requests http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24448/2602

Comment: How can we change the running as user, as we having in standard functionality