# Trigger on Casesolution object

Tags: solutions

I am looking to update a Case field whenever a existing solution is associated to a case.. I realized that I cannot write trigger on Casesolution object and in sfdc developers forum, I found one more user had a similar requirement, but did not mention the workaround for it...

Has anyone implemented this before or any suggestions..

I tried to write a trigger on Solution with the below query and retrieve the case id, but the case or solution record does not get updated when a case is associated to existing solution, so the trigger on the solution never gets fired..

Select id, (Select CaseId from CaseSolutions), SolutionName from Solution where id='XXXXXXXXXXXX'

Answer (score 2):

Neither Case nor Solution triggers fire and you can't create workflows on CaseSolution either :(

I think the only solution would be to control how Solutions are related to Cases by creating your own VF page to handle this - this then gives you your "trigger" to "do stuff" at the point a Solution is associated to a Case.

Comment: excellent - yes, a similar solution has been proposed for doing stuff with OpportunityContactRole, another object w/o trigger support. The VF page can be an inline page on the std layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use timed Apex that runs the trigger handler on new records modified since the last time it was run.

Steps would be something like the following:

1. Implement the trigger code in an Apex class that works on well with bulk records (like you should do anyway) (let's call it `MyTrigger`)
2. Add a Custom Setting called something like `LastUpdateDatetime__c` with a name (the trigger name) and a datetime (`LastDatetime__c`).  Create one called `MyTrigger` and put in a null datetime.
3. Set up a scheduled Apex that runs every X hours and runs `MyTrigger` against the earliest 200 `CaseSolution` records based on `LastModifiedDate` that's greater than the `LastDatetime__c` in  the `LastUpdateDatetime__c` custom setting for `MyTrigger`.
4. When finished, update the `LastUpdateDatetime__c` custom setting for `MyTrigger`.  Set the `LastDatetime__c` field to the greatest `LastModifiedDate` you updated.

Comment: Ah yes, this concept is another way if you can afford the delay. I would consider using scheduled apex. @Charles what's a timed workflow rule? WFs are triggered by events on objects - what object would you create the WF on?

Comment: or use the dan appleman generic async apex pattern which can run almost continuously (every few secs)

Comment: @ForceHero Thanks.  I am relatively new to the SF world.  I meant Scheduled Apex.

Comment: @crop1645 sounds interesting, do you have a link to the pattern please? :)

Comment: @ForceHero -- http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/24448/2602 -- and also the 2nd edition of his book which has improved code samples

Comment: @crop1645 if you wanted to spell out how to apply that idea in this context, it would be a valuable answer to this question.