# Modify batch class already in schedule

Tags: apex, batch, class, schedulebatch, scheduled

How can I modify a batch class that is already placed in a schedule. I have deleted the Scheduled job and still getting error to modify the corresponding batch class. Can someone please help me here?

> Compile error:  This Apex class has batch or future jobs pending or in
>   progress; This schedulable class has jobs pending or in progress

Comment: Take a look at [How to deploy apex classes that are scheduled](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24446/how-to-deploy-apex-classes-that-are-scheduled) and also this [Deploy with Active Jobs](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_deploy_with_jobs.htm) linked from Daniels answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code on your developer console.

```
list<string> ids = new list<string>();
list<CronJobDetail> cjds = [select id from CronJobDetail];

for(CronJobDetail cjd : cjds){

    ids.add(cjd.id);

}
list<CronTrigger> Cts = [select id from CronTrigger where CronJobDetailId IN :ids];
for(cronTrigger ct: Cts){
    system.abortJob(Ct.id);
}
```

Comment: this will abort every job

Answer (score 1):

Please remove scheduled batch job manually if you are trying to modified it, then you can continue to modify it.

[image]